# Is there any difference in meaning between "I canoe" or "I go canoeing" when someone asks you if you play any sports?

Tags: difference, collocations

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *I canoe* or *I go canoeing* when someone asks you if you play any sports? For example:

> Person A: Do you play any sports?
>
> Person B: I **canoe**/I **go canoeing**

Comment: Not sure if this good enough to be an answer but they are very similar and either would probably work in most situations.  I think that "I canoe" would probably be more common and would imply a slightly higher level of interest/participation than "I go canoeing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are very similar and either would probably work in most situations, however I (native AmE speaker) think that "I canoe" would probably be more common and would imply a slightly higher level of interest/participation than "I go canoeing".

For example, if someone said "I go canoeing", I would assume every once in a while they go someplace, rent a canoe and have a fun time doing it.

If someone said "I canoe" I would assume they most likely owned their own canoe and paddles and did it frequently.

Answer (score 1):

go canoeing, go skating, go riding, go mountain climbing, go skiing, go surfing as well as many others are a common way to describe many sports' activities. And the activities are also referred to with gerund nouns:

Canoeing is fun.
Skating is hard.
Climbing is dangerous. etc.

Also, to describe a particular instance of practicing a sport, one can say:

I skied on Saturday. [aka went skiing]
I surfed on Wednesday. [went surfing]
I canoed on Sunday. [went canoeing]

The single verb without go can always be used to describe doing a sport:

I played [tennis, golf, basketball] on Sunday.

So, the verb canoe is no different than any other verb used for engaging in a sport....